php-fpm: pool domain.com memory leak
using nginx and php7.3-fpm I run into a huge problem.
Using
watch -n 1 "ps -eo rss,cmd --sort=-rss | grep 'php-fpm' | awk '{cmd=\"\"; for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) cmd = cmd \$i \" \"; rss[cmd] += \$1} END {for (cmd in rss) printf \"%.8f GB: %s\\n\",  rss[cmd]/1024/1024,cmd}' | grep 'php-fpm: pool mydomain.com' | grep -v 'grep php-fpm'  | awk '{print \$1}'"

I monitor the memory usage of all my running php-fpm: pool example.com processes. It's dynamic, 150 idle processes and 1 running - so everything's not that bad.
Now the problem is, that the Memory consumption of my process increases every time I open a website like https://www.example.com/script.php, and the script has this code :
<?php
exit();
?>

After running this code, the memory used by php-fpm: pool example.com processes increases and does not drop after the script is finished. So this looks like a memory leak to me. What is the reason behind it?

When debugging such problems, not using 6 year old software would be a starting point. Upgrade to a supported release.

you mean php-fpm version? my software is not ready for this (. But is this the only way? It can't be that 7.3 hat such a HUGE problem, right?

Who knows. It's not maintained any more, so problems are not fixed. EOL was in 2021.

ok I'll check another version, but maybe someone knows how to check or fix this problem here

Ok, I tried php8.1-fpm - same problem! the memory is not being released. So this is not related to the 7.3 version. Can someone help me?
